# What's $\frac{\partial}{\partial X} f(X\otimes A)$?

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

Based on the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2391112/matrix-chain-rule-question-what-is-fracddx-fs-where-s-ax-1?rq=1), I wonder how, using the differential notation, one finds $\frac{\partial}{\partial X} f(X\otimes A)$?

Assume that $X,A$ are positive definite matrices, and we know what is $\frac{\partial}{\partial U} f(U)$.

Edit: I have in mind this specific $f(U)=d^\intercal U d$

My try:
I'll rewrite f as $f(X)=d^\intercal (X\otimes A)d$. We know that if $d=vec(D)$, then $(X\otimes A)d=vec(ADX^\intercal)$. Therefore, $d^\intercal(X\otimes A)d=d^\intercal vec(ADX^\intercal)=Tr(D^\intercal ADX^\intercal)$

so, we have $f=D:ADX^\intercal$, then
$df=D:AD \ dX^\intercal=(AD)^\intercal D : (dX)^\intercal$.

Now since f is scalar, we have $df=D^\intercal AD \ dX$ which produces

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial X} f =D^\intercal AD$$

Comment: What $\otimes$ means?

Comment: @AlexSilva kronecker product

Comment: See theorem 11 (page 488) of [this](http://www.janmagnus.nl/papers/JRM012.pdf) paper.

Comment: @AlexSilva it's a bit different from what I could see... The theorem in the paper treats the case "$f\circ g$" and I want "$g\circ f$".

Comment: What you've done makes perfect sense.

Comment: @greg Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Greg, and the answers in the linked questions to this one (see section above, on the right)

I'll rewrite f as $f(X)=d^\intercal (X\otimes A)d$. We know that if $d=vec(D)$, then $(X\otimes A)d=vec(ADX^\intercal)$. Therefore, $d^\intercal(X\otimes A)d=d^\intercal vec(ADX^\intercal)=Tr(D^\intercal ADX^\intercal)$

so, we have $f=D:ADX^\intercal$, then
$df=D:AD \ dX^\intercal=(AD)^\intercal D : (dX)^\intercal$.

Now since f is scalar, we have $df=D^\intercal AD \ dX$ which produces

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial X} f =D^\intercal AD$$